# Javascript- Dynamicly Change Background Image Based On The Last String Of The URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cakephp-3.0

I have had some help from @Ariel Davis. My URLS are dynamically generated from a single template. I want the background image of the dynamically generated page to match the URL.

EXAMPLE: URL: http://my.mysite.com/media/surfing , I would like to dynamically get the image in my /assets/main/img/ folder 'surfing.jpg and display it as the background.

Here is my current CSS:

```
.main_background{
background: url('/assets/main/img/athlete_background.jpg') no-repeat  top center;
background-size: cover; 
min-height:600px;

}
```

My current Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    //Change banner image
    var loc = window.location.pathname
    var img = loc.substring(
        loc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, loc.length
    ) + ".jpg"
    $("main_background").css( 
        "backgroundImage",
        "url(" webroot/assets/main/img/ + img + ")" 
    )
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @Ariel Davis here is my code, sorry new to Stack Overflow and did not know how to edit my last question.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript for this for a reason? It seems to me that there are server-side solutions (perhaps involving small changes in the layout file) that might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this just before the closing body tag:

```
<script>
    (function(){ 
        var loc = window.location.pathname;
         var img = loc.substring(
             loc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, loc.length
             ) + ".jpg";

        $(".main_background").css("backgroundImage", "url('webroot/assets/main/img/" + img + "')");
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: my apologies for the late reply, the code now shows a quick flash of the original background image and then it shows nothing for a background image. Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the "webroot" in the url and it worked perfectly, thank you for you assistance, greatly appreciated.